# i try to increase my logo size in header section with the css but it split

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

My logo is split whenever i try to increse its size in the header. This is the logo.

[image]

```css
header {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycpfl.png);
  background-size: 50px;
  /*if i increse the size my logo is croped*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
</body>
```

Comment: If you want to change the logo size, you should probably adjust the width and height properties.

Comment: Can you show the DEMO, Jsfiddle?

Comment: i try to change width and height but it won't change

Comment: don't turn SO into a support desk, please. This question should be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very unlikely to help any future visitor.

Comment: The background crops because you are only increasing the background but not the container `div`, increase the container `div`, problem solved.

Comment: Remove `background-size: 50px;` us only `height: 330px;` and ` width: 300px;`

Comment: What does "my logo is split" mean? Are you sure you want to use it as a background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes because you are giving height to header 50px. it will fine if background-size is also 50px. but it will crop if you increase size of the background-size.
you also have to increase the height of the div. so it will be fine.

also you can give  background-size contain. so image will be load in it's full size and it will also not split.

```css
header {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycpfl.png);
  background-size: contain;
  /*if i increse the size my logo is croped*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  background-position:center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
</body>
```